# trying to understand props with React-Native and Redux

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm learning RN and Redux, but cannot get over the hump of data passing. I made the below code as a test to update, push, and pull data from firebase, but the input text (although being applied to state with infoUpdate) does not make it into info object.

Im sure the answer is very simple, but I am a complete noob.

Thanks!!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { infoPull, infoPush, infoUpdate } from '../actions';
import { Card, CardSection, Button, Confirm, Input } from './common';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

class FeedbackInput extends Component {



  onButtonPress() {
    const { info } = this.props;

    //this.props.infoPush({ information });
    console.log("HERE_HERE_HERE_HERE_HERE", info, "BREAK_BREAK")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Input
            label="Name"
            placeholder="Awesome Group"
            value={this.props.info}
            onChangeText={text => this.props.infoUpdate({ prop: 'info', value: text })}
          />
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
          <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
            Send Info
          </Button>
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}



const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { info } = state;
  return { info };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { infoPull, infoPush, infoUpdate })(FeedbackInput);
```

this is the printout: HERE_HERE_HERE_HERE_HERE null BREAK_BREAK

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is a scope problem.

You have to bind your onPress method with the scope of the constructor like this :

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //your state's initial state
    };
    this.onButtonPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
  }
```

Otherwise this.props is not defined in your method ;)

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example looks correct, assuming infoUpdate is a bound action creator. The issue seems to lay within your redux layer.

Did you at all verify that state.info is not null?
Need to see more code.